# R: How to extract the intercepts of 1000 linear regressions and put them in one data set?

Tags: r

I did a bootstrap(a linear regression replicated 1000 times with replacement) and got 1000 intercepts(alpha) and 1000 slopes(beta),

```
msft.boot.sample <- list()  
for (i in 1:1000) {
  msft.boot.sample[[i]] <- sample(y_msft,size = 132, replace = TRUE)
}
x.boot.sample <- list()
for (i in 1:1000) {
  x.boot.sample[[i]] <- sample(x, size = 132, replace = TRUE)
}
n <- 1000
my_lms <- lapply(1:n, function(i) lm(msft.boot.sample[[i]] ~ x.boot.sample[[i]]))
sapply(my_lms, coef)
summaries <- lapply(my_lms, summary)
```

Then,

```
coef(my_lms[[1]])["(Intercept)"]
# (Intercept)
# -0.0366332

coef(my_lms[[2]])["(Intercept)"]
# (Intercept)
# -0.01598145

coef(my_lms[[3]])["(Intercept)"]
# (Intercept)
# -0.02526318
```

I can get the one intercept and one slope at a time, but how to get all the alphas(or betas) in a time and put them in a data set?
I used a code like that but still got only one value of alpha.

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
  alpha.1000 <- as.numeric(coef(my_lms[[i]])["(Intercept)"])
}

alpha.1000
# [1] -0.03495652
```

Comment: Just a note for future writing of code blocks, either indent a line by four spaces or use the `{}` icon on selected text to indent multiple lines.

Comment: Got it :) i know it looks wired...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are always overwriting the alpha.1000 value. Use this:

```
alpha.1000=numeric(1000)    
for(i in 1:1000){ 
      alpha.1000[i]<-as.numeric(coef(my_lms[[i]])["(Intercept)"])
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way you have a typo it should be "alpha.1000=c()" Haha!

Comment: You know from the start that there are 1000, so even better will be `alpha.100 = numeric(1000)`.

Comment: Oops, fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your regressions all have the same parameters, then

```
coef_list = sapply(my_lms, coef)
```

will give you a matrix with a column for each model and a row for each coefficient. A vector of intercepts is just the top row, `coef_list[1, ]`.